# Meaning of the sentence with verb drag

Tags: meaning

How would you interpret this sentence?
"my persistence dragged me to solve it"

Comment: Did I not advise you to add some research in your closed question? [Usage of verb “drag”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366065/usage-of-verb-drag) A simple dictionary reference would have been sufficient.

Comment: Seeing as two users have already cast their votes to close this question, I will also cast mine, only two more needed and this under-researched question will be closed. (Typical, give [**good advice**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366065/usage-of-verb-drag#comment854063_366065) and people ignore it.... mutter... humbug...)

Answer (score 0):

The implication is that your persistence continued to strive solving the difficult or awkward problem beyond what you would normally have done. There were obstacles in your path that you needed to be forced to overcome.

While *dragged* is the verb of the sentence, it is almost acting like an adjective by expressively amplifying the meaning of *persistence*.